# How do I use a callable object as a method definition?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know it's possible to define a function and use it as a method:

```
def method(*args, **kwargs):
    print "%r %r" % (args, kwargs)

class Test(object):
    method1 = method

t = Test()
t.method1()  # (<__main__.Test object at 0x10705a4d0>,) {}
```

I'd like to do the same thing with callable objects, like this:

```
class Method(object):
    __call__ = method

class Test(object):
    method1 = Method()
```

However, when I do this, the `self` argument of `Method.__call__` is the method itself (which is normal), but the `self` argument of the `Test` instance is lost.

```
t = Test()
t.method1()  # (<__main__.Method object at 0x10703f110>,) {}
```

Is it possible to have the `self` argument passed as the second argument to `Method.__call__`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By wrapping that function `method` in a class you are effectively preventing the mechanism that binds an object to a function and thus creates a method. The way this works is that regular python functions are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods).

To summarize the docs: When you write the following code:

```
some_instance.some_function()
```

The `some_function`s `__get__` method is called with `some_instance` as the first parameter. The `__get__` method then returns a bound method object, that remembers the instance. Later, when the bound method object's `__call__` method is called, it passes the saved instance as a first parameter.

We can reimplement that behaviour like this:

```
def method(*args, **kwargs):
    print("%r %r" % (args, kwargs))


class BoundMethod(object):
    # the bound method remembers the instance and the function
    def __init__(self, instance, function):
        self.instance = instance
        self.function = function

    # when the bound method is called, it passes the instance
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)


class Method(object):
    # the __get__ method assembles a bound method consisting of the
    # instance it was called from and the function
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return BoundMethod(instance, method)


class Test(object):
    method1 = Method()


t = Test()
t.method1()  # (<__main__.Test object at 0x7f94d8c3aad0>,) {}
```

In your case `Method` is not a descriptor. So, when internally the `__call__` property (which is a function) is requested it is bound to an object of the containing class (`Method`).

I am not sure if this is useful, as this example is just a simplified version of what happens under the hood anyway.

Note: in this example:

```
class C:
    def function(self): pass

print(C.function)
print(C().function)
```

The first print shows us, that an unbound method literally is called `<unbound method C.function>` while a bound method is called `<bound method C.function of ...>`.

In python3 however the first print shows us that unbound methods are just the unchanged functions we defined in the class.

Comment: Thanks! I’m not in front of my computer, but I’ll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: In addition to what you said, it's possible to use `types.MethodType` to create a new, completely normal `instancemethod` descriptor that uses any callable object (but `instancemethod` needs you to provide the type object, which can be inconvenient in some contexts).

Answer (score 3):

Yes: make the method a **descriptor**—which, as already noted by Wombatz, is the mechanism used by normal method binding.

```
class Method(object):
  def __get__(self,obj,cls):
    def method(*args, **kwargs):
      print type(obj)   # to illustrate what object we get
      print type(self)  # we have the Method too
      print "%r %r" % (args, kwargs)
    return method
```

Notes:

1. It would also be possible to forward to the `__get__` on a function and produce a legitimate bound method object, but this way you have `self` **and** `obj` available.
2. `obj` is `None` if the method is looked up on the **class itself** (`Test.method1`, rather than `Test().method1`); you can decide separately what to do (with `cls`) in that case.