# Callable object as method not passing self as an argument

Tags: python

Updates:
Adding the following **get** function will solve the problem:

```
class clsB():
    def __call__(self,self_from_class_a):
        print(self_from_class_a)
        pass

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return lambda *args,**kwargs:self.__call__(instance,*args,**kwargs)
```

I recently encounter a problem when I try to use a callable object as method of an object.

```
class clsB():
    def __call__(self,self_from_class_a):
        print(self_from_class_a)
        pass

callable_b = clsB()

def fnB(self_from_class_a):
    print(self_from_class_a)


callable_b('x')
>>> x
fnB('x')
>>> x
```

Well Basically "callable_b" and "fnB" would behave the same, so it is reasonable to think that it will work when I do the following:

```
def dec(fn):
    return fnB

class A:
    @dec
    def a(self):
        pass

A().a()
>>> <__main__.A object at 0x1051ba4a8>

print(A().a)
>>> <bound method fnB of <__main__.A object at 0x10d44e4a8>>

Works Great!! fnB has became bound method fnB But...

def dec(fn):
    return callable_b

class A:
    @dec
    def a(self):
        pass

A().a()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self_from_class_a'

print(A().a)
>>> <__main__.clsB object at 0x10f372470>
```

Can anyone explain why it is the case?

Comment: Is there anyway python would consider my callable object as "function" @TomKarzes

Comment: I found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044943/how-do-i-use-a-callable-object-as-a-method-definition