# Why don't callable attributes of a class become methods?

Tags: python, methods, language-lawyer

Consider the following snippet.

```py
import types

def deff(s):
    print(f"deff called, {s=}")

lam = lambda s: print(f"lam called, {s=}")

class Clbl:
    def __call__(s):
        print(f"__call__ called, {s=}")

clbl = Clbl()

print(type(deff) == types.FunctionType)  # True
print(type(lam) == types.LambdaType)  # True
print(type(clbl) == Clbl)  # True

class A:
    deff = deff
    lam = lam
    clbl = clbl

a = A()
a.deff()  # deff called, s=<__main__.A object at 0x7f8c242d4490>
a.lam()  # lam called, s=<__main__.A object at 0x7f8c242d4490>
a.clbl()  # __call__ called, s=<__main__.Clbl object at 0x7f8c24146730>

print(a.deff is deff)  # False
print(a.lam is lam)  # False
print(a.clbl is clbl)  # True

print(type(a.deff) == types.FunctionType)  # False
print(type(a.lam) == types.LambdaType)  # False
print(type(a.clbl) == Clbl)  # True

print(type(a.deff) == types.MethodType)  # True
print(type(a.lam) == types.MethodType)  # True
```

Why are `a.deff` and `a.lam` methods but `a.clbl` not a method? Why do the expression `a.deff()` and `a.lam()` pass `a` as the first argument to the corresponding functions while `a.clbl()` doesn't?

Comment: Try [How do I use a callable object as a method definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54044943/3890632)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR `Clbl` doesn't implement the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); `types.FunctionType` does.

---

All three attempts to access attributes on `a` fail to find *instance* attributes by those names, and so the lookup proceeds to the class. All three lookups succeed on *class* attributes, at which point it is time to see which, if any of them, define a `__get__` attribute.

`a.clbl` does not, so you get back the actual `Clbl` instance bound to the class attribute.

`a.deff` and `a.lam` do (there is *no* significant different in between the two; `types.LambdaType` itself is just an alias for `types.FunctionType`, because lambda expressions and `def` statements both create values of the same type). `types.FunctionType.__get__` is what returns a callable `method` object, which his what manages the implicit passing of an invoking instance to the underlying function.

In short, `a.deff()` is equivalent to

```
A.__dict__['deff'].__get__(a, A)()
```

The `method` object does three things:

1. Maintains a reference `__self__` to the instance `a`
2. Maintains a reference `__func__` to the function `A.deff`
3. Implements a `__call__` method that calls `self.__func__` passing in the required positional argument `self.__self__` along with any other arguments it was called with.

---

As a side note, the descriptor protocol only applies to *class* attributes. The `__get__` method, if any, of a function-valued *instance* attribute is ignored.

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
a.foo = lambda: 3
```

Since `foo` is an instance attribute, `a.foo` is resolved as `a.__dict__['foo']`, not `a.__dict__['foo'].__get__()`.